# Programming assignment: "Blaster Master"

Tags: javascript, html

I have been doing a project in a Javascript/HTML5 class that has been stumping me. I am supposed to make an image bounce around the screen, and whenever it's clicked, your score will go up one. If you fail to click the image, you will lose one of five lives. Here is a video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QS-vxrZrEK4&feature=youtu.be

The thing that I am having problems with is the click detection. How do I detect that?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
            <style>
                body{cursor: none; overflow: hidden;}       
            </style>    
        </head>

        <body onload="startBall()" oncontextmenu="return false;" onclick="loseLife()">
            <audio src="portal.mp3" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop"></audio>
            <div id="div" style="width: 1600px; height: 745px; border: 2px solid #000000; background-color: grey;">
                <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1600" height="745"></canvas>
                <br>
                <img draggable="false"id="image1" style="position: absolute; display: none;" width="50" height="50" src="http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/evil/images/5/59/The_Death_Star.png/revision/latest?cb=20150810042957"/>
                <img draggable="false"id="image" style="position: absolute;" width="50" height="50"src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/b/a/b/0/1207156679935151925noxin_crosshairs.svg.hi.png"/>
            </div>

            <script>
                var width = 50;
                var height = 50;
                var dx = 3;
                var dy = 3;
                var x = 600;
                var y = 300;
                var z = 0;
                var lives = 5;
                var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
                var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
                var interval;
                var img=document.getElementById("image1");

                function startBall(){
                    interval = setInterval(launchBall, 20);
                }

                function launchBall(){
                    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1600, 745);
                    var image = ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, width, height);
                    if(x<0 || x>1470) dx=-dx;
                    if(y<0 || y>700) dy=-dy;
                    x = x + dx;
                    y = y + dy;

                    ctx.font = "30px Arial";
                    ctx.fillText("Score: " + z,10,50);

                    ctx.font = "30px Arial";
                    ctx.fillText("Lives: " + lives,10,100); 

                    image.onclick = function() {fire()};
                }

                document.getElementById("div").onmousemove = function(e) {
                    document.getElementById("image").style.top = e.pageY -25 + "px";
                    document.getElementById("image").style.left = e.pageX -25 +"px";
                }

                function addScore(){
                    z = z + 1;
                    ctx.font = "30px Arial";
                    ctx.fillText("Score: " + z,10,50);
                }

                function loseLife(){
                    lives = lives - 1;
                    if (lives == 0){
                        stop();
                        ctx.font = "100px Arial";
                        ctx.fillText("Game Over",500,400);  
                    }else{
                        ctx.font = "30px Arial";
                        ctx.fillText("Lives: " + lives,10,100);
                    }           
                }

                function stop(){
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1600, 745);
                }

                function fire(){
                    score = score + 1;
                }
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I am not an html pro, but I think the reason it's "failing" is because of how your "onclick" is defined in body (html section) and image in script. I suspect body gets priority for clicks (or script onclick doesn't trigger. Either way try removing that onclick from HTML body section, stop the movement of image (so you know you're not missing) and see if your score increases when you click it.